# Powerpoint VBA to switch back to powerpoint from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I hope someone can help....

I have a powerpoint presentation, which has linked tables and graphs from an excel file. the updating of the slides are set to manual.

i have created a VBA code in Powerpoint which opens up the excel file. I am trying to update the links in the powerpoint through VBA instead of manually choosing each linked element and updating the values. while the first part of my VBA code works in opening up the excel file, the links are not being updated, which i think is down to not being back in the powerpoint to update the links, so I am trying to include in my VBA code lines which will go back to the powerpoint presentation, after which i assume the the line to update links will work (happy to be corrected). below is the code i have built so far....my comments are in bold ...

any suggestions?
FYI, I am using office 2007.

Thanks

```
Sub test()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("File location\filename.xlsm", True, False)

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
```

**Section above opens the excel file which contains the linked tables and charts**

```
On Error Resume Next
  With GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    .ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Activate
  End With
```

**Section above i was hoping would go back to the powerpoint after opening the excel file but it does not which is why i think the code below to update links is not working**

```
ActivePresentation.UpdateLinks


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Start from something easier. This will allow you to activate the first existing PowerPoint application from Excel:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ppt As New PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.visible = msoTrue
    ppt.Windows(1).Activate

End Sub
```

Then play a bit with it and fix it into your code.

Comment: Thanks for responding. if i am not mistaken, your code above you will call the powerpoint from excel so this code will need to be in excel. however, the code i have provided is in powerpoint, which opens the excel file, but i then need to go back to the powerpoint the code is being run from. hope that is more clear.

Comment: sorry, no, my reply was posted before i finished.

Comment: @Morph314 - I see. How about simply changing `xlApp.Visible = True` to `False` and trying with your code? Or try going with `xlApp.WindowState = xlMinimized`

Comment: Changing True to false was the first ting i tried before posting on here, but when i run the macro, ppt hangs for a while, does not open the the excel file. for the minimise piece, would i enter that code after xlApp.Visible = True?

Comment: @Morph314 - Just try it before and after. :) Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` on the top as well.

Comment: Tried variouse combinations to add the above, no luck....i think i will have to find another way of doing this, annoying as all i want to do is switch back to the powerpoint screen!!

Answer (score 0):

@Vityata

Ok, i got it to work....original coding did the first part of opening the excel file, and to switch back to powerpoint (and i think this will only work if there is only 1 presentation open i added the following code...

AppActivate "Microsoft PowerPoint"

so my complete code looks like:

Sub test()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp.Visible = True

Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("file path\file name.xlsm", True, False)

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing
**AppActivate "Microsoft PowerPoint"**

End Sub

now to get manual links to update as part of the vba code...

Answer (score 0):

If you capture the file that your macro is in.  This is just a string of your path and filename

```
'This is the macro file
MacroFile = ActivePresentation.FullName
```

Then you can use that variable to activate just that specific PowerPoint presentation.

Use Presentations(MacroFile).Activate
or Presentations(MacroFile).Updatelinks

It's best not to use ActivePresentation when moving between applications.

Comment: thank you, and a great shout...however, the powerpoint file which contains the macro will have different names every month, so i would have to change the VBA every month. out of curiosity, where would you enter "MacroFile = ActivePresentation.FullName" part, after "Dim xlWorkBook As Object" bit?

Comment: Doesn't matter what the file name is , this captures the file name of the current active presentation.  So when you run the macro, the file that contains the macro should be the active presentation.     Add the line of code at the beginning of your macro.